# Facebook Graph API recipe to extract public trends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, is there an endpoint or some 'recipe' (similar to Twitter's) which enable a developer to capture public trends from Facebook Graph API?

This could be in any form such as, hashtags, posts or likes. The only known solution seems to be the [Facebook Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed) but the access is limited.

Comment: no, there is no api for that

Comment: It seems like that to me as well. Any recipes I might be able to use?

Comment: what do you mean? there is no api for it, so there is no way.

Comment: well, we could use available features for a recipe.

Comment: what features? if there is no API, then there is no way. scraping is not allowed on facebook.

Comment: What I mean is available features like the posts from one's own timeline or etc. If we could use the number of likes for the most recent posts or some other means...

Comment: you get the posts from your own timeline by authorizing with user_posts. that´s not "public trends" then, that´s only "liking trends of your own posts".

Comment: Yeah , you are right. I think it is very silly of me to think that way but I am just thinking whether we could use any available resource (since there is no specific public trends API) along with some calculation, for this purpose. Maybe if you could post this as an answer I will be able to accept.